# MS Excel count occurrences

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have excel columns as follows:

```
Name,Name1
Name,Name3
Name1,Name3
Name3,Name4,Name
```

Now I want a function that will give count of each unique name on all rows. For example output

```
Name = 3
Name1 = 2
Name3 = 3
Name4 = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**:
Select the data and use text to columns to split them into seperate columns:

[image]

Result:

[image]

**Step 2**

Move your data to 1 single column:

[image]

**Step 3:**

Create a pivot table

[image]

Though you could always use a VBA solution.

Comment: You way is best if the names are all in one column!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the names are spread over three columns, pick a cell and enter:

```
="Name = " & COUNTIF(A:C,"Name")
```

and then the same for the other names.

Comment: ahh, this is much better :)

Comment: Thanks for your answers, just accepted the first answer as the question was related to excel. However decided to do it using java as familiar with processing text with java.